# Passar parâmetro do tipo ROWTYPE com o comando EXECUTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Estou desenvolvendo uma função em Postgres que tem como objetivo recuperar para cada registro de uma consulta o valor de resultado de uma verificação contida em um conjunto de funções. Destas funções somente uma devolverá o valor correto. Estas funções tem um prefixo comun *'fn_condicao_'* e recebem como parâmetro um objeto do tipo *'minha_table'*.

Como o número de funções que fazem a verificação não ser conhecido, resolvi consultar o catálogo do Postgres, a partir da tabela *pg.catalog.pg_proc* buscando por funções com o prefixo *'fn_condicao_'* e executá-las dinamicamente a partir do comando [EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

A minha dificuldade está em como passar o parâmetro de forma correta para o comando EXECUTE.

**Como indicar no trecho comentado na função abaixo `'select ' || funcoes.proname || '(' || registro || ')';` que a entrada é do tipo minha_table?**

```
create or replace function testa_condicoes()
returns void as 
$$
declare
    registro minha_table%rowtype;
    funcoes pg_proc%rowtype;    
begin 
    set search_path = 'pg_catalog';

    for registro in (select * from minha_table where id in (1,2,3)) loop
        for funcoes in (
            SELECT  p.proname
            FROM    pg_namespace n
            JOIN    pg_proc p
            ON      p.pronamespace = n.oid
            WHERE   n.nspname = 'operacional'
            and p.proname like ('fn_condicao_%')
            order by p.proname) 
        loop
            --execute 'select ' || funcoes.proname || '(' || registro || ')';
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

#### Exemplo das funções

```
create or replace function fn_condicao_1(registro minha_table)
returns bigint as 
$$
begin 
    if (registro.atributo1 > registro.atributo2) then
        return 1;
    end if;
    return null;
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em versões superiores a versão **8.3** é possível usar a expressão `USING` para fornecer parâmetros. Esta versão, contudo, não possui suporte a essa sintaxe. Para usar parâmetros de forma apropriada é recomendado o uso das funções `quote_ident(text)` e `quote_literal(value)` conforme exemplificado abaixo:

```
execute 'select ' || quote_ident(funcao) || '(' || quote_literal(registro) || ')';
```

### Solução

A função abaixo postada como solução requer algumas observações, pois difere em alguns pontos da função postada como dúvida.

- A atribuição de 'pg_catalog' a search_path [não é necessária](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CATALOG), pois o esquema 'pg_catalog' já é incluido nos esquemas pesquisados em search_path.
- O caractere '_' usado na condição `like` deve ser escapado, pois quando não escapado representa um [coringa que casa qualquer caractere único](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html).

#### Função testa_condicoes:

```
create or replace function testa_condicoes()
    returns void as 
    $$
    declare
        registro minha_table%rowtype;
        id_condicao bigint;
        funcao text;    
    begin 
        set search_path = 'operacional';

        for registro in select * from minha_table where id in (1, 2, 3) loop
            for funcao in (
                SELECT  p.proname
                FROM    pg_namespace n
                JOIN    pg_proc p
                ON      p.pronamespace = n.oid
                WHERE   n.nspname = 'operacional'
                and p.proname like ('fn\\_condicao\\_%')
                order by p.proname) 
            loop
                execute 'select ' || quote_ident(funcao) || '(' || quote_literal(registro) || ')' into id_condicao;
                raise info 'id_condicao: %', id_condicao;
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end;
    $$ 
    language plpgsql;
```

---

#### Fonte:

**Executing Dynamic Commands**
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html

**Passing ROWTYPE parameter to EXECUTE** https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127001/passing-rowtype-parameter-to-execute

Answer (score 0):

O principal problema da sua função é que você tem que retornar um valor `row` como em `select my_table from my_table`. Eu dei uma simplificada:

```
create or replace function test_conditions()
returns void as $$
declare
    r record;
begin 
    for r in 
        select my_table, p.proname
        from
            my_table
            cross join
            (
                select p.proname
                from
                    pg_namespace n
                    inner join
                    pg_proc p on p.pronamespace = n.oid
                where
                    n.nspname = 'operacional'
                    and
                    p.proname like ('fn_condition\\_%')
            ) p
        where my_table.id in (1,2,3)
    loop
        execute 'select ' || r.proname || '(' || replace(r.my_table, ',,', 'null') || '::mytable)';
    end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Note que a consulta dentro do laço `for` não tem parêntesis. `pg_catalog` é um identificador e a utilização de aspas neste caso está deprecada. De qualquer forma o esquema `pg_catalog` sempre faz parte do `search_path` e não é necessário incluí-lo.

Comment: Olá, Clodoaldo. Testei sua solução. Ela apresenta o mesmo resultado que o já alcançado por mim, um erro na execução da query: ERRO:  erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "," at character 37. QUERY:  `select fn_condicao_1((6566,14,9999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,A,"2016-01-14 11:18:59.140774",1,,,,,,,,,0,))`

Comment: @Geison: Eu atualizei a resposta colocando o cast para `::my_table`. No 9.5 funcionou sem o cast mas talvez a sua versão não faça o cast automático

Comment: Ele aprensenta a mesma mensagem de erro do comentário anterior. A diferença está no cast incluido: `::my_table`

Comment: @Geison: Como ele está retornando uma string ao invés de `my_table` então eu coloquei um `replace` e mantive o cast: